# Как создать столбец с вычисляемым значением в HSQLDB?

Tags: java, junit, hsqldb

В jUnit тестах используется HSQLDB версии 2.7.2 для создания DB в памяти (in-memory DB).
Для создания таблицы используется SQL скрипт, примерное содержимое которого приведено ниже. Проблема заключается в том, что определённый столбец использует вычисляемое значение (computed) используя значения нескольких других столбцов, которые могут содержать NULL значения. Это вычисляемое значение используется как некий ключ *(даже не спрашивайте меня почему так - кровавый энтерпрайз)* и использует разделитель между значениями. Ожидаемое/требуемое поведение таково, что при NULL-значении разделитель всё равно должен присутствовать.

```sql
-- SQL скрипт src/test/resources/t.sql

CREATE TABLE t(
id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
first_name varchar(50) NULL,
middle_name varchar(50) NULL,
last_name varchar(50) NULL,
full_name varchar(150) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (first_name || ',' || middle_name || ',' || last_name)
-- так тоже пробовал
-- full_name varchar(150) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT(first_name, ',', middle_name, ',', last_name))
-- full_name varchar(150) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT_WS(first_name, ',', middle_name, ',', last_name))
);
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO t (first_name, middle_name, last_name) VALUES ('a', NULL, 'b');
INSERT INTO t (first_name, middle_name, last_name) VALUES ('c', 'd', 'e');
INSERT INTO t (first_name, middle_name, last_name) VALUES ('f', NULL, 'g');
COMMIT;
```

Пример создания вычисляемого столбца [приведён](https://hsqldb.sourceforge.net/doc/2.0/guide/guide.html#N10E97:%7E:text=fullname%20VARCHAR(40)%20GENERATED%20ALWAYS%20AS%20(firstname%20%7C%7C%20%27%20%27%20%7C%7C%20lastname)) в документации.

Также пробовал использовать [CONCAT](https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N11C66) и дополнительно указывал в строке подключения параметр `sql.concat_nulls=false` и `sql.concat_nulls=true`, так как [согласно документации](https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N11C66:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20any%20null%20value%20will%20cause%20the%20function%20to%20return%20null.%20If%20the%20property%20is%20set%20false%2C%20then%20NULL%20values%20are%20replaced%20with%20empty%20strings) при наличии NULL хотя бы у одного конкатенируемого значения CONCAT вернёт NULL, но никакого эффекта этот параметр строки подключения не принёс. В приведённом примере вычисляемые значения (full_name) будут `a,b`, `c,d,e` и ``, так как ни одно из используемых значений не содержит NULL, а необходимые значения должны быть `a,,b`, `c,d,e` и `f,,g`.

Другими словами, оба приведённых варианта создания столбца с вычисляемым значением не работают с NULL.

**Каким образом создать вычисляемый столбец используя значения других столбцов содержащих NULL в HSQLDB?**

---

#### Использование CONCAT_WS

[Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) [предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1536332/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%86-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b2-hsqldb?noredirect=1#comment2761982_1536332) использовать [CONCAT_WS](https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N11C84), и да это работает, но в этом случае [NULL-значениях игнорируются](https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N11C84:%7E:text=The%20function%20ignores%20null%20values%20and%20returns%20an%20empty%20string%20if%20all%20values%20are%20null.) и вместо `a,,b` или `f,,g` мы получаем `a,b` и `f,g` соответственно (вне зависимости от параметра `sql.concat_nulls` в строке подключения).

---

#### Примерное использование

```xml
<!-- фрагмент pom.xml -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>${hsqldb}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/sqltool -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqltool</artifactId>
    <version>${hsqldb}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```java
// фрагмент jUnit теста
static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
{
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;"
        + "sql.lowercase_ident=true;"
        + "sql.enforce_names=true;"
        + "sql.enforce_refs=true;"
        + "sql.truncate_trailing=false;"
        + "get_column_name=true"
        + "shutdown=false"
        + "sql.syntax_mss=true"
        + "hsqldb.applog=3"
        + "hsqldb.sqllog=3"
        // хоть true, хоть false - одно и то-же поведение
        // + "sql.concat_nulls=true"
        + "sql.concat_nulls=false", "SA", "");
}

@Test
void computedColumnTest() throws SQLException, IOException, SqlToolError
{
    try (Connection _con = getConnection())
    {
        java.sql.Statement _stmt = _con.createStatement();

        // так выбрасывает исключение
        // java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: CONCAT
        // _stmt.execute("SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX CONCAT NULLS FALSE");
        
        var _file = new File(this.getClass().getResource( "/t.sql" ).getFile());
        var _sqlFile = new SqlFile(_file);
        _sqlFile.setConnection( _con );
        _sqlFile.execute();

        String _sql = "SELECT id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, full_name FROM t";
        ResultSet _resultSet = _stmt.executeQuery( _sql );
        while(_resultSet.next())
        {
            int _id = _resultSet.getInt( 1 );
            String _firstName = _resultSet.getString( 2 );
            String _middleName = _resultSet.getString( 3 );
            String _lastName = _resultSet.getString( 4 );
            String _fullName = _resultSet.getString( 5 );
        }
        _stmt.execute( "SHUTDOWN" );
    }
}
```

---

#### Ссылки на документацию HSQLDB

- [создание таблицы](https://hsqldb.sourceforge.net/doc/2.0/guide/guide.html#N10E97)
- [использование CONCAT](https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N11C66)
- [использование CONCAT_WS](https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N11C84)

Comment: `full_name varchar(150) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, middle_name, last_name) )` Будет ругаться на функцию - удвойте скобки вокруг выражения...

Comment: Вы ищете функцию COALESCE. `COALESCE(NULL, 'abc') == 'abc'`. Если нужно, чтоб для вместо null использовалась пустая строка при катенации, то `COALESCE(first_name, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(middle_name, '') || ' ' || COALESCE(last_name, '')`

Comment: @Akina большое спасибо за Ваш совет, но это не подходит. Дополнил/обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA предложенное Вами решение работает. Оформите, пожалуйста, ответом.

Comment: *и вместо a,,b или f,,g мы получаем a,b и f,g соответственно* Предупреждать надо... кто мешал показать не только пример данных, но и требуемый результат для них?

Comment: @Akina извините, пожалуйста. Никто не мешал - я сам виноват.